How to update the jQuery and jQuery-UI latest version
I AM using jQuery- v1.9.1 and jQueryUI- v1.10.3, but i need to update this as latest version how to update this files. can you please help me to update this file.
iam getting some methods as mismatch error.
I replaces the files in our project .older version to new version of jQuery 3.7.1 and jQuery ui-1.13.3 but still it's not working. please guide me to update to the latest version.

"this file": there is no file in your post. Have you followed the guides that are available on jquery.com? Like https://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/3.0/ There is also a migration tool here: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate

Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide a [mcve].

I'm guessing from the way you've posed the question, its a downloaded file that you have in your project, I would strongly advice to use a CDN instead with the following hyperlink https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.js and it will load the latest jQuery file into your projects.
If you want to use a file instead navigate to their site jQuery and download from there, however as I said, you should use a CDN and link it in the <head> </head> section of your application. You can link it with a script tag as follows <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.js"> </script>
